# Firefox addons: It is possible to programmatically block the permission for notifications for the specific URL similar to Chrome API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Does Firefox extension API have a similar method for setting the notification permission for the specific URL? Using chrome API you can set:

```
chrome.contentSettings.notifications.set({primaryPattern: "www.example.com", setting:"block"})
```

For Firefox, the only similar method I found:

```
browser.browserSettings.webNotificationsDisabled.set({value: "false"})
```

but this sets the permission globally and not per site, which is possible to set in Chrome. It seems that Firefox doesn't have this level of detail in its API to set this permission programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The "**contentSettings**" is not available for Firefox. It is only available for Google Chrome, Edge, and Opera.
See this browser compatibility overview:
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#:~:text=Toggle%20history-,contentSettings,-Yes](https://contentSettings)